# Optimize Relationship Building between Many neo4j Nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a database containing two particular node types: `GenomicRange` and `GeneModel`. The `GenomicRange` node set contains ~80 million nodes while `GeneModel` contains ~45,000 nodes.

The `GenomicRange` nodes contain a property `posStart` which is stored as an integer. The `GeneModel` node contains two particular integer properties `geneStart` and `geneEnd`. These coordinates are found on a `chromosome` property found in both node types (e.g. `1` through `10`).

What I would like to do is to *efficiently* create relationships (e.g. `[:RANGE_WITHIN]`) between these two nodes if (1) Their chromosome properties match, (2) if the `posStart` value in `GenomicRange` falls within range of the `geneStart` and `geneEnd` properties on the `GeneModel` node.

My problem I am currently having is that my querying/building process is incredibly slow. Is there a way to optimize this code?

Thanks for your help!

```
MATCH (model:GeneModel)
WITH model
MATCH (range:GenomicRange)
WHERE range.chromosome = model.chromosome AND range.posStart >= model.geneStart AND range.posStart <= model.geneEnd
CREATE (range)-[:RANGE_WITHIN]->(model)
```

Answer (score 1):

Few suggestions:

**Add index on the properties you are using for comparison.**

Here: posStart, chromosome, geneEnd, geneStart.

```
`CREATE INDEX ON :GenomicRange(chromosome)`
```

**Increase Heap Memory:** Creating index increases memory usage so increase heap size up to 50% of your memory. You can configure this in `neo4j.conf` file.

**Increase page cache:** more the cache size more the data cached in memory, It will help avoid costly disk access.

Read more about memory configuration [here](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-performance-tuning/#_memory_configuration_guidelines).

**P.S.** ***If you still get out of memory error after increasing heap size, swap `GenomicRange` and `GeneModel` on line 1 and 3 OR use `APOC plugin` to create relationships periodically.***